# Calling snippets inside another snippet

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, j#

```
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    ......

    <Snippet>

     .......

        <Code Language="vjsharp" Format="CData">
            <![CDATA[ 

                  ====== here i need to call another snippet code part =======
            ]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

I have a block like this for example, if i need to insert another snippet code in this means how to do that ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a snippet from another snippet. Simply copy-paste the code of the other snippet where you need.